# Exception Value: Word matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'word__iexact': u'abc/action'}

Tags: django

I am using Django urls.py to pull a value from the URL, here is my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^word/(?P<w>.+)/$', 'myapp.views.word'),
    url(r'^word/(?P<w>.+$)/action/', 'myapp.views.action'),)
```

The first item: `myapp.views.word` works well and accepts the variable that is entered: `/word/asdf` and I am able to manipulate `asdf` how I choose in my views.py.
The second item `myapp.views.action` gives me the error

```
Exception Value:    
Word matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'word__iexact': u'asdf/action'}
```

This is a part of my `views.py`:

```
def action(request, w):
    o = Word.objects.get(word__iexact=w)
```

I would like for when the user goes to `/word/asdf/action` then I can run my `action` view upon the `asdf` parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: here it seems that you are trying to access /word/asdf/draw, not action, so it matches the first url definition, not the second one. if you want to save an "action" variable you have to add a second regexp or you have to exclude '/' from your regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `r'.+'` matches also the "/" characters, and it acts greedy so it matches all the last part of the URL. For this reason you are never calling the second definition, both `/asfd/` and `/asfd/action/` will match `^word/(?P<w>.+)/$`
(see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request, point #3)

Try with this in your url.py:

```
 url(r'^word/(?P<w>.+)/(?P<action>.+)/$', 'myapp.views.action'),)
```

and in your views.py

```
def action(request, w, action):
    o = Word.objects.get(word__iexact=w)
    # do something with "action" variable and "o" object
    #...
```

**OTHERWISE** you can simply use a less greedy regexp like this:

```
     url(r'^word/(?P<w>\w+)/$', 'myapp.views.word'),)
     url(r'^word/(?P<w>\w+)/action/$', 'myapp.views.action'),)
     url(r'^word/(?P<w>\w+)/draw/$', 'myapp.views.draw'),)
     # and so on...
```

for further details you can always refer to python docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: the action is not a variable, it is a static part of the URL. do I still need to use the same syntax?

Comment: I still am getting the error: `Lookup parameters were {'word__iexact': u'dog/action'}`  It is taking the entire url: dog/action as `w`, where `w` is only supposed to be dog.

Comment: you have to change also the first url definition using \w (I've further edited my answer to highlight this)

Answer (score 2):

You misplace `$` that's why the action is in your parameter

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^word/(?P<w>.+)/$', 'myapp.views.word'),
    url(r'^word/(?P<w>.+)/action/$', 'myapp.views.action'),)
```

Comment: +1 this is also true, but it is not the reason why the action is in his parameter, the reason is the order of the url pattern, and the first pattern is too generic :)